# Startswith(): more arguments

Tags: python, string

is there a function in python to check whether a string starts with a certain number of possibilities? 
For example, I'd like to check whether string A starts with "Ha", "Ho", "Hi". I thought I could use `string_A.startswith("Ha", "Ho", "Hi")`, but unfortunately, this is not possible :(

Thanks for any advice! :)

Comment: [Pass them in a tuple.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass them as a single tuple:

```
>>> "Hi, there".startswith(('Ha', 'Ho', 'Hi'))
True
>>> "Hoy, there".startswith(('Ha', 'Ho', 'Hi'))
True
>>> "Hello, there".startswith(('Ha', 'Ho', 'Hi'))
False
```